# Snowflake regexp & split

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have column values that are in between starting of the underscore(*) and ending with an underscore(*).

I am trying to see how to extract a value between 2 underscores (_). for example, "**xxxx_Whats your number 23345_xxxxx**".

I want to discard everything before and after underscore(_).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[REGEXP_SUBSTRING](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html), using a grouping match `( )` and turning on sub-matches `'e'`, and selecting the first match.. then stating you want to see an underscore, and then many not underscores, and then a underscore.

```
select 
    column1, 
    regexp_substr(column1, '_([^_]*)_',1,1,'e')
from values
('xxxx_Whats your number 23345_xxxxx')
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMN1, '*([^*]*)_',1,1,'E') |
| --- | --- |
| xxxx_Whats your number 23345_xxxxx | Whats your number 23345 |

hmm, you mention discard before and after, thus if you want to include the underscore you will need to move them into the grouping brackets:

```
select 
    column1, 
    regexp_substr(column1, '_([^_]*)_',1,1,'e') as exclude_underscore,
    regexp_substr(column1, '(_[^_]*_)',1,1,'e') as include_underscore
from values
('xxxx_Whats your number 23345_xxxxx'),
('has no first underscore_xxxxx'),
('xxx_has no last underscore'),
('nothing between__the underscores');
```

| COLUMN1 | EXCLUDE_UNDERSCORE | INCLUDE_UNDERSCORE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxxx_Whats your number 23345_xxxxx | Whats your number 23345 | _Whats your number 23345_ |
| has no first underscore_xxxxx | null | null |
| xxx_has no last underscore | null | null |
| nothing between__the underscores |  | __ |

then you might also want, atleast 1 character between the underscrores, and thus should change the `*` to a `+` or a `{n,}`